# Positioning origin CSS

Tags: css

I notice when positioning in CSS:

```
.image {
    position: relative;
    top: 10%;
    left: 50%;
}
```

The "origin" is always the top-left. Is there anyway of changing this origin to say the centre?

Comment: What's your ultimate goal? I feel like you're falling victim to the AB problem. Changing the origin of the element mightn't be what you're really after.

Comment: setting top:50% left:50% is equivalent to center

Comment: or you can try with `margin : 0 auto`

Answer (score 5):

Setting `top` and `left` properties on `.image`  you're setting the position of the top-left corner relative to it's normal position;

in a relative positioned block inside a wrapper that will be the same origin of the wrapper-parent (supposing there aren't any other sibling nodes that influence position);

setting `top:50%; left:50%` you're moving the origin to center of parent.

If you want to correct the origin to be the center of image you can use `transform:translate(-50%,-50%)` (this positioning is relative to the width/height of `.image` )

here's an example :

```css
.image {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    background:red;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%)
}

section{
    width:100%;
    height:600px;
    border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div class='image'></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

No.

> The key to understanding how these properties work with relative positioning is to realise that they specify the **edge** that the movement is applied to, not the direction of movement.
>
> In other words, the top property shifts the box relative to its top edge, the left property shifts the box relative to its left edge, and so on. The box is shifted away from the specified edge, so top:1em shifts the box 1em away from the top position—in other words, downwards. Negative numbers shift the box in the opposite direction, so bottom:-1em is the same as top:1em.

**Source:** [**W3 org Wiki**](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_static_and_relative_positioning)

The alternative is using CSS3 transforms.

The *default* origin (transform-origin) for transforms is `center center`.

Answer (score 0):

To find the center of anything 2D you divide its width, and height by two.

You can do that and center something with CSS position with calc() like this:

```
top: calc(50% - (HEIGHT / 2));
left: calc(50% - (WIDTH / 2));
```

Example:

```
.origin-center {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - (36px / 2));
  left: calc(50% - (42px / 2));
  height: 36px;
  width: 42px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

No. The possible absolute/relative/fixed positioning origins are `top`, `left`, `bottom`, `right`.

Comment: What's the downvote for? I've answered the question... Even if it is a poor question

Comment: It's actually not a poor question, it's just not something that's typically asked about CSS and layout.

Comment: Then it is the question that should be downvoted, not the answer... Especially without an explanation

Comment: Actually you have misunderstood the question.

Comment: @LcSalazar - read my comment again. It's, in my opinion, *not* a poor question. Thus, it doesn't deserve a downvote.

Answer (score -2):

```js
$(window).on('resize', function () {
    $('.img_name').css('margin-top', function () {
        return ($(window).height() - $(this).height()) / 2
    });
}).resize();
```

```css
.img_name{width:150px;margin:0 auto;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="img_name"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RN9nh.png?s=328&g=1" width="150px" alt="" /></div>
```

use this it's support all viewports.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question it might be helpful to include an explanation of what this code is doing and how it relates to the OPs question. Especially since the question was about `position` and not `margin`.